# How to implement Bullets and numbering UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter-web

I need to create a screen that has bullets kind of feel like in the image I have attached. But I have no clue on how to get this started. So any help would be highly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iei8C.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `ListView.builder`.

Firstly you need a List of objects. Create an object which holds four variables:

bool isSelected,
String iconUrl,
String title,
String trailing,

Then return a `ListTile` in the ListView.builder

Keep two network images, one grey (to be used when isSelected = false), the other blue, when isSelected is true.